# Android programatically create UI based on dynamic data

Tags: android, xml

There are many questions here in SO regarding programmatically creating UI in android, but my question is the best approach to efficiently display dynamic data.

**Requirement:** I want to display text data from `SQLite` database and display it with proper formatting. ie, Title with different color than rest of the text, different background color/drawable for some part of the text and so on..there are many rows of data and each row of text might be having different number of title,subtitle, body etc.. and the size of text stored is pretty large.

**Problem:**
1. If I create UI in xml for each text I have to create a separate layout as the number amount of text stored in database is very high this approach is won't work.
2. If I store data as HTML in database and display it in a `TextView`  only basic formatting can be applied.

**My current approach:**
Store data in `SQLite` in the form of `XML` with proper tags to distinguish title,subtitle, body etc.. Parse the `XML` data and create views programmatically for each tag with proper formatting. With this approach I can display any number of rows of data from database with a single piece of code which creates the UI.

Is there any approach better than this? Please share your suggestions.

Comment: Why not just have separate columns in the table for "title,subtitle, body etc."? Also, I fail to see how your solution is any easier than option #1 -- in fact, it should be substantially harder.

Comment: @CommonsWare There may be many title, subtitle in a text. I cannot determine the exact number.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated the question. The advantage which i feel with my approach is that if there are 100 rows just a single piece of code can create UI for all those 100 rows of text, which would could not be achieved easily if I have used XML layout.

Comment: You can use html UI with WebView and communicate with UI with jockeyjs https://github.com/tcoulter/jockeyjs